Epson imagescan deleted after upgrade to 24.04 from 22.04
I have been using Epson imagescan (termed all-in-one here: https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) with V550 under 20.04 & 22.04 w/o problems. After upgrade to 24.04, the imagescan package had disappeared. Instead Epsonscan2 appeared (flatpak), which works but does not have the same features as imagescan for scanning photos (dias & negatives).
Side note: epsonscan2 from the Epson repository above does not work, aborts when trying to find scanner.
I have tried to reinstall imagescan but cannot get it to work, always get the msg: 'Could not send command to scanner'.

Today I tried again to install imagescan and it now works!
The only change I made prior to installing was to downgrade from libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb to libsane_1.1.1-5_amd64.deb as suggested here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2498203&page=2&p=14193152#post14193152
No proof that this solved the problem though.
Thanks.

This question is similar to: Installing Epson Iscan For Linux. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
